# u-SQL - is it possible to reference a registered assembly from a code-behind file

Tags: u-sql

Registered assemblies can be used in u-SQL script files by using REFERENCE ASSEMBLY.
Is it possible to reference a registered assembly in a c# code behind file?

Comment: Just using the `using` statement in the code-behind file?  Does that work for you?

Comment: To reference a class library that is within my solution that works great - I just add the project reference to the U-SQL project, add the `using` statement and it's all fine. I would like to know whether it is possible to reference an assembly that is not in my solution, but has been registered in a u-SQL database, from a c# code behind.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to have the assembly interface available for building the local assembly that will be created from the code-behind file. You can download the assembly from the cloud explorer/server explorer in VisualStudio if you don't have it.

And you will need to have the REFERENCE ASSEMBLY statement for the U-SQL database registered assembly in the U-SQL script to make sure that the assembly will be available when you execute your script.